# Two questions on finite abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which of the following are true?

1.Every group of order $6$ abelian.
2.Two abelian groups of the same order are isomorphic

Comment: Neither is true.  $S_3$ is non-abelian of order $6$, and $\mathbb{Z}_4\not\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: None. As the symmetric group on three elements isn't abelian, but of order 6 and $\mathbb Z/(4)$ and $\bigl(\mathbb Z/(2)\bigr)^2$ aren't isomorphic.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is an instance of (what I find to be) an archetypical problematic question on this site: someone asks a question about groups which can be answered by calling attention to $Z_2 \times Z_2$ or to $S_3$.  To the OP: have you really not been exposed to symmetric groups and products of finite cyclic groups??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

none of them is true.
for 1. consider $S_3$.
for 2. consider $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Answer (score 5):

HINT: At this point you should have seen two groups of order $6$, $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ (sometimes called $\Bbb Z_6$) and $S_3$, and two groups of order $4$, $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ (sometimes called $\Bbb Z_4$) and the Klein $4$-group. Are both of those groups of order $6$ Abelian? Are those two groups of order $4$ isomorphic? How do you know?